# What is failure analysis of PBCA?

Tags: board, analysis, failure

I do not know whether this is the appropriate place to post this question but i guess its related to electronics. Basically i'm doing some research on what is the term for **"PBCA"** in failure analysis?
 (eg As used [in this job advertisement](https://jobs3.netmedia1.com/cp/job_summary.jsp?st=6316&job_id=ISC-0441714) )

What does it stand for? And what does it have to do with debugging of board failures?

Thank you for your precious feedback.. I appreciate it :)

Comment: If googling it doesn't result in much, then it's not a standard term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"PBCA" is a typo.
 They should have used the abbreviation  "PCBA",
 which is common industry jargon for "Printed Circuit Board Assembly".

You may otherwise uses the term "circuit board" or "populated PCB".
 The A on the end of PCB signifies a PCB with components assembled on it.

So, their line which reads

- Experience in failure analysis of PBCA will be added advantage

simply means,

- "it would be advantageous if you have had experience  in systematically  working out what failures have occurred in faulty circuit boards".

Their wording "will be added advantage" is poor English.
 If they wanted to keep the wording brief the line would ideally read something like

- Experience in failure analysis of PCBAs would be an added advantage

---

I just sent them the following email.
Will be interesting to see if they change it:
Error and change are bold, coloured and large in email

---

To:  "buzzhr@sg.ibm.com"

On page https://jobs3.netmedia1.com/cp/job_summary.jsp?st=6316&job_id=ISC-0441714

Where you have

```
       Experience in failure analysis of PBCA will be added advantage
```

You may perhaps mean

```
        Experience in failure analysis of PCBA will be added advantage
```

regards

```
        Russell McMahon
        Applied Technology ltd
        New Zealand.
```

Comment: Aha - the phantom downvoter strikes again. Anomalous* as usual. Inexplicated as usual. (* Yep. I seen).

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but maybe you mean "PCBA"? That stands for printed circuit board assembly.

Comment: Because i'm researching based on a actual site here --> https://jobs3.netmedia1.com/cp/job_summary.jsp?st=6316&job_id=ISC-0441714 but i have no idea what is it? By the way i'm only a student researching in the area of engineering..

Comment: Seeing it in context, I'm quite certain they meant PCBA. (What a terrible job description, by the way! It's an entry level job, but they want someone who knows Java, SQL, process control, and circuit debugging. Ridiculous.)

Comment: @pingswept is right. For clarification: a PCB is an empty board, a PCBA is a PCB with the components fitted.